# Java 11 Predicate lambda expression generic type ClassCastException

Tags: java, predicate, java-11

I have problem on java 11 predicate lambda expression generic type , when I write predicate as lambda expression is not returning exactly generic parameter ,and `ClassCastException` occurs , code seen below

**Explaination** 
When we write lambda expression , Generic Parameter method  `getGenericInterfaces()[0] -> ClassCastException` occurs this line because there no generic parameter seen when I  debugged code , seen as just Condition not `Condition<<Integer>>`, anyway when we define predicate as seen below (working case) , its working

Working Case

```
Condition<Integer> oddValueCondition = new Condition<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer integer) {
        return integer % 2 == 0;
    }
};
```

Not Working Case

```
Condition<Integer> oddValueCondition = integer -> integer % 2 == 0;
```

interface definition

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Condition<T> extends Predicate<T> {
    default Class<T> getParameterType() {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
        Type[] typeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        Class<T> type = (Class<T>) typeArguments[0];
        return type;
    }
}
```

Test

```
oddValueCondition.getParameterType();
```

So what do you think problem is , when  write lambda expression ?

And also I created issue on the github [OpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1462)

if they says `TypeReference` Hack is not work on anonymous class and lambda expression , I will accept answer

Comment: Works fine on my environment,
I'd suggest to check the java language level in project settings

Comment: Have you tried casting `Condition<Integer> oddValueCondition = (Condition<Integer>) integer -> integer % 2 == 0;
`

Comment: @edwgiz  environment   language level 11 , jdk 11.0.4

Comment: @Karim is not working still same ...

Comment: Does not work on  Windows 10 running java 13.

Comment: @edwgiz What is your environment?

Comment: @WJS Win10 , Java 11, latest IntellijIDEA

Comment: @edwgiz  and you are certain the Lambda version works.  Can you add the following into the interface and see what it prints with both versions. 
 Lambda and anoymous class `System.out.println(this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]);`

Comment: @WJS sorry guys, my mistake, it prints `interface Condition` without generics

Comment: I think  @sleiman answer is correct , Lambda expressions and anonymous inner classes dont compile same byte code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expressions and anonymous inner classes don't compile to the same `byte-code`.

The `TypeReference` hack doesn't work with lambda as the type information is not available through this API. And by the way, this has been like this since Java 1.8.

Comment: hmm , i couldnt find any document on it , so could you show offical document on this issue , otherwise if anyone is accept that , we can sign  as answer.

Comment: And also I created issue on the github https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1462

Comment: @MithatKonuk it isn't a bug and was discussed here sometime ago

Comment: i did not created as bug , opened as issue and  okay then we can take as a answer